# illegal offset type laravel on "trial_ends_at" date

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, model, php-carbon

This is my code. I want to save a user with free trials of 30days in laravel cashier. I try to set the value of `trial_ends_at` but I got the following error:

> error :  Illegal offset type

Controller :

```
$user = User::create([
    'name'          => $data['name'],
    'email'         => $data['email'],
    'password'      => $data['password'],
    'role'          => 'admin',
    'company_id'    => $Company->id,
    'trial_ends_at' => Carbon::now()->addDays(30),
]);
```

Model :

```
protected $dates = [
    'created_at',
    'updated_at',
    'trial_ends_at',
];
```

The function :

```
 protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient(env("STRIPE_SECRET"));
        $Company = Company::create([
            'name' => $data['company'],
            'unique_hash' => str_random(20),
        ]);

        $settings = [
            'currency'=> 3,
            'time_zone' => 'UTC',
            'language' => 'fr',
            'fiscal_year' => '1-12',
            'carbon_date_format' => 'd M Y',
            'moment_date_format' => 'DD MM YYYY',
            'notification_email' => $data['email'],
            'notify_invoice_viewed' => 'YES',
            'notify_estimate_viewed' => 'YES',
            'tax_per_item' => 'YES',
            'discount_per_item' => 'YES'
        ];
        CompanySetting::setSettings($settings, $Company->id);
        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => $data['password'],
            'role'  => 'admin',
            'company_id' => $Company->id,
            'trial_ends_at' => Carbon::now()->addDays(30),
                               
        ]);

        $userSetting = [
            'language' => 'fr'
        ];
      //  $user->trial_ends_at = Carbon::now()->addDays(30);
        $user->setSettings($userSetting);  
       $user->createOrGetStripeCustomer();
       // $user->updateDefaultPaymentMethodFromStripe();
   //    $user->newSubscription('default', $price)->create(null);
      return $user;
    }
```

Comment: In your model, have you added 'trial_ends_at' to your $fillable array?

Comment: @GilesBennett no need to add it to th fillable array

Comment: I disagree. The ::create method is a mass assignment and therefore the $fillable property of the model in question needs to be defined to specify which attributes of that model are mass assignable. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#mass-assignment

Comment: show `$Company` variable doing `dd($Company)`

Comment: @GilesBennett also if i add it in fillable array the error persist but the field got the value in database

Comment: @LeenaPatel no the error is showin when I set trial_ends_at

Comment: So (a) there was a need to add it in the fillable array. The error does not appear to be in the create::() method. So show the rest of your code.

Comment: @GilesBennett I edit the code in the question take a look

Comment: OK, well, you're accessing a myriad of arrays in there - the error, I imagine, is because you're trying to access something in an array by passing it an object, not a key. Debug your arrays and you should come across it.